# pgPool containers restarting in docker swarm cluster

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, pgpool

I have a docker swarm cluster with 3 hosts, There I have deployed a postgres with pgpool.
containers are distributed as below

```
Host01 - pgPool/Postgres(pg-0)/pgAdmin
Host02 - pgPool/Postgres(pg-1)
Host03 - pgPool/Postgres(pg-2)
```

Traffic comes to pgPool via a load balancer. When regular transactions are happening this is working fine and replication also happening pretty normal. But when bulk transactions are happening (batch processing) all the pgPool containers restart with the below error.

```
2023-12-11 19:08:01: pid 1: LOG:  shutting down
2023-12-11 19:08:01: pid 1: LOG:  terminating all child processes
```

No any other useful log prints here.
When I tail logs of pgPool container it always keep printing below logs. (even when it is running healthy). I don't know that this error relates with the pgPool restarting issue, but it is always keep printing.

```
2023-12-11 19:07:47: pid 1156: DETAIL:  EOF encountered with frontend
2023-12-11 19:07:52: pid 1: LOG:  child process with pid: 341 exits with status 256
2023-12-11 19:07:52: pid 1: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1285
2023-12-11 19:07:52: pid 1: LOG:  child process with pid: 446 exits with status 256
2023-12-11 19:07:52: pid 1: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1286
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  child process with pid: 465 exits with status 256
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1301
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 343: ERROR:  unable to read data from frontend
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 343: DETAIL:  EOF encountered with frontend
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  child process with pid: 207 exits with status 256
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1302
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  child process with pid: 346 exits with status 256
2023-12-11 19:07:56: pid 1: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1303
```

Can someone please help me to identify the issue for this pgPool restarting issue while heavy transactions.

Versions - Postgres 13 / pgPool 4.2.1